# Is there an end in Hill Climb Racing?

Tags: hill-climb-racing

Is it infinite? Has anyone seen its end?

Comment: I think that the answers to the question "Are the levels of Hill Climb Racing procedurally generated?" (https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/235624/145662) provide some well cited and authoritative answers to this question.

Comment: Most are endless, some have an end.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hill Climb Racing is indeed infinite - there is no end goal or finish line. Instead, it is a game based purely on high score.

Comment: Do you have a source for this? It just keeps generating road?

Answer (score 1):

One of my friends got the game when it was new.  It did have a finish line back then and he's sure there is still one but he thinks it is way beyond what any of the vehicles can reach.

Answer (score 1):

Every 20 levels, you will arrive to the starting point without feeling, because the stage is designed to have a starting point that is similar to the finishing point.

Comment: What are you trying to say?

Comment: Sounds like he might be saying that it doesn't end because you just go back to the beginning again. Maybe: "Every 20 levels you will be returned to the starting level without noticing, because it is designed so that the last stage and the first stage are similar." Something like that.

Answer (score 1):

It most definitely has an end. I've made it in one level a long time ago but I don't remember which one. I trust that they may have made it longer but there is an end as it's a set course. If it was infinite the track would be generated at random instead of being the exact same every time. It doesn't make new tracks as you go so it is set in the software of the game. So yes I believe it most definitely has an end and since they made it farther than it used to be it is beyond the car's capabilities. That's why they added the garage so you can build the perfect car for each course!

Comment: That doesn't necessarily mean it's infinite. You can seed a PRNG, which will generate the same pseudo-random numbers in the same order every time.

Answer (score 1):

There is an end in **Space mission** it says **space survivor**.
If you ride the **neon dragon**(**neon**),**survive the troll**(**ragarnok**) and **Collect all 10 treasures** i.e become jungle king (**jungle**)the level is pretty much accomplished

Answer (score 0):

Hill Climb Racing is currently never ending. The goal is to see how far you can make it, therefore getting a higher score, how much money you can collect, and how many vehicles and parts you can unlock.