# Are levels in Hill Climb Racing procedurally generated?

Tags: hill-climb-racing

In Hill Climb Racing, your progress is limited by a few factors: crashing, running out of fuel and reaching unclimbable obstacles. However, after playing the game for some time, I have still seen no indication of any level actually "ending".

Are they procedurally generated and go on forever, or are they just hand crafted to such a distance that nobody can reach the end in practice? Maybe a combination?

This question *may* have been asked before, but [the accepted answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/215182/117521) interpreted that question as one about game progression rather than level length, and the accept kind of "closed" that one.

*Now, I am aware that the **practical** answer would be likely to be "It doesn't matter if they end, you can't get to that point anyway", but I would still like to know (it may require some official source).*

Comment: Ask the developer. Any answer you get is likely to be speculation.

Comment: @DangerZone Unless somebody allready did, and I just couldn't find the source for it (hence the question) :)

Comment: I just got 3,000,000+ coins and 10,628m using Big Finger on Highway and was dying when it just. Never. Ended. Finally ran out of gas. Surely, someone knows if these levels end. Does it really just keep making more road? UGH! No closure. Insomnia is not my friend...

Comment: @MeatTrademark I just got 19583 meters on Highway with Kiddie Express! No end....

Comment: It also seems **Zombie HQ** never ends. Bought everything, reached the goals (except the *one* goal that requires you to spend actual money) and the game still goes on.  NO CLOSURE.

Comment: @Svj0hn I got an answer from the developers, I'd be glad if you checked it out!

Answer (score 7):

**Major Edit:**

I asked the developers (support@fingersoft.net) and this is the reply I got:

> Sami-jukka Piippo (Fingersoft)
>   Aug 30, 09:08 EEST
>
> Hello,
>
> Some of the stages are hand made and some are procedurally generated. Go see how far you can get! ;)

So, that's the final answer. **Some stages are made by a seed and some are hand-crafted** (eg. Nuclear Plant repeats every 5-6 km from the beginning).

Comment: Just to add an additional level of authority to this answer, Sami-jukka Piippo is the support lead for Fingersoft, which can be seen on his LinkedIn profile. https://www.linkedin.com/in/sami-jukka-piippo-0712938b/

Answer (score -2):

The levels are not procedurally generated. Play a level with a bridge twice. The bridge will be in the same place.

Comment: That doesn't really mean anything, as it would just indicate the same seed being used.